# Spring Boot custom whitelabel error dev vs prod

Tags: spring-boot

I have an Spring Boot rest API with some custom error for 401, 404, 500 and with 2 yml profiles: application-dev.yml and application-prod.yml.

My project structure is like this:
resources ->   templates ->     error

- 401.html
- 404.html
- 500.html

For the custom error i use thymeleaf.

I want to show this custom errors only in production, in development i need the default "WhiteLabel Error".

Is this possible ?

Comment: refer to https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-custom-error-page

Comment: @WonChul Heo how is this useful ?